# How to run or debug on android phone instead of emulator?

Tags: android, android-emulator

Android emulator is so slow that it is not possible to test run applications. Is there anyway to debug/run applications on real phone with IDE instead of emulator?

Comment: Do you have a device? if so which one? the process is differs for many available devices to get it set up using ADB

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You can generally switch on USB debugging on your handset and connect it up to your PC over USB. The handset will then appear to adb in the same way as an emulator. You might need to download drivers from your handset manufacturer for your phone.

On my HTC desire the setting is under:

> **Settings** -> **Applications** -> **Development** -> **USB Debugging**

Comment: how do i safely detach my device once i use it for debugging etc? it always says it's in use and i'm not sure what's using it. even after closing eclipse ect.

Comment: Note: On Android 4.2 and newer, Developer options is hidden by default. To make it available, go to Settings > About phone and tap Build number seven times. Return to the previous screen to find Developer options. 7 times!

Answer (score 12):

Enable USB-Debugging on your phone. Connect it to your computer. ADB should recognize it and you can use it the same way as a virtual device.

If ./adb devices lists your phone as a lot of question marks, then it is lacking some permissions. To fix this, restart the adb server as root. Something on the line of:

```
~$ ./adb devices
List of devices attached 
emulator-5554   device
?????????????   device  <--- your phone
~$ sudo -s
~# ./adb kill-server
~# ./adb devices
List of devices attached 
emulator-5554   device
1232345345345   device  <--- your phone
```

Comment: The server is called adb.exe (inside the platform-tools folder of your android SDK installation) and I *suppose* you need to run it as local administrator if you get permission issues. Maybe somebody who uses windows could give more specific instructions.

Comment: After that, if I still get question marks, what could be wrong?

Answer (score 4):

I realize the context is for Windows, but I had the same issue on Linux (Fedora).  Creating a new file in /etc/udev/rules.d/ was necessary (and restarting adb as Hyperboreus indicates).

This is indicated clearly at http://developer.android.com/tools/device.html.

fwiw

Answer (score 4):

For Windows Users:

```
1. Go to Command Prompt
2. Type cd /path/to/adb.exe
3. Type adb.exe devices
4. Type adb.exe kill-server
5. Type again adb.exe devices
```

If you get your Device, Its fine. If not, Try once again.